# How to get the table name that contains a certain ID?

Tags: javascript

I have several tables that contain an ID with the word "MRCPUBSY"
(Example: `TABLE ID="_MIPS-MRCPUBSY"`).

How  can I get this table if I only know a part of the ID NAME?

I thought to use something like: 
`var MyTable = document.getElementById('MRCPUBSY'.value)`
but this is not okay because the NAME of the ID is _MIPS-MRCPUBSY **and not just** MRCPUBSY.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [*attribute contains* selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings), `[id*=MRCPUBSY]`.

For instance, to get the first such table:

```
var myTable = document.querySelector("[id*=MRCPUBSY]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [attribute contains selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview):

```
document.querySelector("[id*='MRCPUBSY']").value;
```

Comment: thankss for the answer